# How to retrieve other users from a Firebase app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm learning JavaScript and I'm trying to built a social app in a specific domain. Nothing big as usual social network because it's for a small community.

1. So I'm using Firebase, JavaScript ES6 and only one HTML file with an `<app>`. I already have and auth system, profile page for the current user. But my problem is that I don't know, understand the way to have pages from other's profile.

   So as far as I succeed to go it's to get the other's users information from by Firebase database. But I'm stuck in my mind. Should I create an HTML file for each user? I don't think so?

   This project is for a certification.
2. And my other problem is and can't make a verification from data. Well I succeed to check if data exist but it doesn't block the process so it updates anyway and get 2 users with the same name (see code below).

[firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt9rh.png)
[Atom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHPVU.png)

```
      savePrenom(event){
        let database = firebase.database();
        event.preventDefault();
        let uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        database.ref('users').once('value', (snapshot)=>{
          snapshot.forEach( el=>{

            if(prenom.value === el.val().prenom){
              console.log('existe déjà');

            }
            if (prenom.value != el.val().prenom){
                  savePrenom.style.display= 'none';
                  editPrenom.style.display= 'block';
                  prenom.disabled = true;
                  database.ref('users/'+uid).update({
                       prenom: prenom.value
                  })
            }
          })
        });

  }
```

Comment: Normally if you have an urgent support requirement, I would advise that you pay for one-to-one assistance via AirPair or TopTal. However since this is for a certification you're probably under academic honesty rules, so I would not advise getting someone to do too much of it.

Comment: This is probably too broad as it stands, so I would recommend rewriting it (a) so that it is only one question, and (b) has some code showing what you have tried. As I understand it Firebase is hosted, so you just need to issue a query for the current user (using a cookie or auth token) and get data to render in a JavaScript template or HTML string.

Comment: yes i know i think i can manage it no need on someone on doing the job for me. But need only help.

Comment: It is not clear what you are stuck on. Are you able to write a Firebase query to list a page of users (e.g. users 1-20) and return that in JSON? You would then have the basis of a paginated list, so you can ask for 21-40 for your next page. For each item in a JSON reply you can convert it back to an object/array and iterate over it to render it in your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys sorry for not responding for all question/answers but i got both solutions.

On the first one. As i could get the informations from a user a simply add some data-classes to passe the data that i could get from firebase. But their was a easier solution. From the moment i can get any information inside a user, i could get the key of each user using snapshot.key (which i forgot). So then it's easy, using a forEach element, each link to each profil use the right information on an other page.

Second question to check if a username already existe when changed for exemple. Well, i started to make a once reference value on my database users. Then if my pseudo.value === el.val().pseudo that means it existe to error message. If not, the user can change his username if wanted with .update for firebase.

```
            database.ref('users').once('value', (snapshot)=>{
              let find = false;
              snapshot.forEach(el =>{
                    if(pseudo.value === el.val().pseudo){
                          //console.log('YEAH');
                          find = true
                    }
              })
              if (find === false) {
                    savePseudo.style.display= 'none';
                    editPseudo.style.display= 'block';
                    pseudo.disabled = true;
                    database.ref('users/'+uid).update({
                         pseudo: pseudo.value
                   })
              }
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your first problem: Do not create a html file for each user, that's terrible!

You should rather fetch the data and then use DOM manipulation to insert your data into the page. I do not know which database you are using so I can not give you a code sample for the fetching but only one for DOM manipulations.

Let's say you have the following html:

```
<p id='description'></p>
```

You can get the element by id and change it's properties, this is known as *DOM manipulation*.

```
document.getElementById('description').textValue = 'Very important'
```

This assigns *Very important* to the paragraph (the text will appear when executed by a browser).

Since you said you use plain ES6 only, I'm not going into backend technologies like NodeJS.

I can not help you with the second one since  I lack information, please submit some code and tell us more about the technologies you are using.

Comment: i edit my post the code is what i use to check if prenom already exist. The console log works but it edits anyway the data in FireBase. I did put 2 if because if i put an else it crashes (using gulp in atom nodeJs)

and for the first part actually to be sure to be clear (sorry for my english). I log in my app. Now i wanna see an other user profil. My question is how ? how to link a specific user. I click on a name and then it could be an other page.js but ....